# split string of spans into array of spans

Tags: html, regex, split

I have a block of text wrapped in spans that I need to split into an array.

So currently I have

```
var s = `
   <span class="hoverable">c</span>
   <span class="hoverable">o</span>
   <span class="not-hoverable">o</span>`;
```

I need

```
var s = [
   "<span class="hoverable">c</span>",
   "<span class="hoverable">o</span>",
   "<span class="not-hoverable">o</span>"];
```

I've tried `s.split(/<\/?span>/);` to split accounting for `<span>` and closing `</span>` but

```
var s = [
  "<span class="hoverable">c", 
  "<span class="hoverable">o", 
  "<span class="not-hoverable">o",...]
```

So it's not including the closing span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when a regexp question wanders over into HTML or XML territory, I suggest regexp is not the right tool. Use the proper HTML parser available in the language you are using. In case of JavaScript (implied by your use of `var` and string template syntax):

```js
let s = `
   <span class="hoverable">c</span>
   <span class="hoverable">o</span>
   <span class="not-hoverable">o</span>`;
let d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = s;
let result = Array.from(d.children).map(e => e.outerHTML);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the DOM if you are working in a browser and the value is inside of an element. If it is not and you have a string then you can still use DOM dynamically. Finally, you can use regular expressions.

Here's a round up:

```js
var s = ' ' +
  '<span class="hoverable">c</span>' +
  '<span class="hoverable">o</span>' +
  '<span class="not-hoverable">o</span> ';
var r2 = s.match(/<span(.*?)>(.*?)<\/span>/gm);
console.log("using regular expressions");
console.log(r2);

function findWithDOM() {
  console.log("using DOM");
  var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv span'));
  console.log(elements);
}

function findWithDynamicDOM() {
  console.log("using Dynamic DOM");
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.innerHTML=s;
  var elements = [].slice.call(element.querySelectorAll('span'));
  console.log(elements);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"><span class="hoverable">c</span>
  <span class="hoverable">o</span>
  <span class="not-hoverable">o</span>
</div>
<input id='btnFind' onclick='findWithDOM()' value='Find With DOM' type="button" />
<input id='btnFind' onclick='findWithDynamicDOM()' value='Find Dynamic DOM' type="button" />
```